# How to write test case for controller that uses Authentication as function argument in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, spring-security

I am completely new to spring boot and trying to write Unit test cases but stuck completely and not able to understand how Authentication works.

Controller class

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getAllConceptsNames")
    public ConceptCO getAllConceptsNames(Authentication authentication) {
        return conceptDelegate
                .getAllConceptNames(PrincipalUtil.getConcepts(authentication));
    }
```

PrincipalUtil.java

```
public final class PrincipalUtil {

    public static Set<String> getConcepts(final Authentication authentication) {
        UserPrincipal user =
                (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Set<String> allConcepts = new HashSet<String>();
        user.getUserPrincipalAttributes().forEach(role -> allConcepts.addAll(role.getConcepts()));
        return allConcepts;
    }
```

UserPrincipalAttributes .java

```
public class UserPrincipalAttributes {
    Set<String> columns;
    Set<String> concepts;
    String role;
    // getter & setters
}
```

UserPrincipal.java

```
public class UserPrincipal implements AuthenticatedPrincipal {
    private String name;
    private Set<UserPrincipalAttributes> userPrincipalAttributes;
    private String token;
    // getter & setters
}
```

Comment: what framework are u using to test , Spring mvc or any Mock framework ?

Comment: @Hades Thanks for replying. I am using Spring Boot Test

Comment: @Hades you can look into my other similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382462/spring-boot-error-org-springframework-security-core-userdetails-user-cannot-be-c where I have tried writing test case. I have been trying it for many days but couldn't understand how it works. Your help is appreciated.